# python problems with decimal place

Tags: python

I have written an transfomator for decimal numbers in an other number system. The number left to the comma i right but the decimal place after the comma is false. I'll poste my code but the variables are in german, so i hope you can read them

here ist the code left to the comma (no mistake)

```
print "decimal numbers to another number system between [2-9]\n"
decimal = float(raw_input("put in a float: "))
base = int(raw_input("base: "))

#declaration for first part
decimalnew = decimal  # we need this var for the second part
result = 0
number = int(decimal) / 1
factor = 1


# first part for integers decimal is always an integer (this part is ok)
while (decimal):
    leftover = int(decimal) % base
    decimal = int(decimal) / base

    factor *= 10
    result = result + leftover * factor

#declaration for second part
decimalnew = decimalnew - number
result2 = 0
factor2 = 1

# second part for floats always < 1 (f.e. 0.2)


# i think in this part is the mistake
while (decimalnew > 0):
    leftover2 = decimalnew * base
    decimalnew = decimalnew * base
    if (decimalnew > 0):
        decimalnew = decimalnew - leftover2 
    factor2 = factor2 * 10
    result2 = result2 + leftover2 / factor2

# results from the first part and the second part
finalresult = result + result2


print "eingegebene Zahl", number, "- neue Zahl mit der Basis %d =" % (base) , finalresult/10
```

Comment: I cannot read German, and am having a hard time understanding your question. What exactly is the expected behavior? What is an example input? And what would you like as an output? And what does your current code do wrong?

Comment: For what I can read. He wrote a program that converts from floating decimal, to floating *any basis*. The part that converts after the comma is wrong.

Basically, `0.5_10 = 0.1_2`, or so I understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answere. Would like to transforme a decimal number in another number system, for example [binary = 2,3,4,5,6, 7, octal = 8 and 9.
I put in a number with var "dezimal" and a "base" for the number system. For example i put in number 10 it puts out in binary and so on...
integers are fine but float are wrong for example if i put in 10.2 the output should be 1010,00110011... and so so but my output is 1010.004 or something like that in binary and thats the probleme

Comment: Please translate the code.

Comment: i updated the code, i hope it's clear now. sry it was my first post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as you use only 0-9 numbers, you cannot process basis greater than 10.

But you have some problems with the decimal part. First is that even if it worked your algorythme has high chance to break because it can lead to inifinite values.

As a simple example : 0.1 in basis 4 gives the infinite value : 0.0121212..

So you must, first add another question for the maximum precision to stop an eventual infinite loop, an next the algorithme for the decimal part must be rewritten.

The following should work :

```
print "reeller Dezimal-Konvertierer\n"
dezimal = float(raw_input("Bruchzahl eingeben: "))
basis = int(raw_input("Basis eingeben: "))
dezpos = int(raw_input("Maximal precision: ")) # don't know how to spell it in german

dezimalneu = dezimal
ergebnis = 0
zahl = int(dezimal) / 1
faktor = 1

while (dezimal):
    rest = int(dezimal) % basis
    dezimal = int(dezimal) / basis

    faktor *= 10
    ergebnis = ergebnis + rest * faktor

dezimalneu = dezimalneu - zahl
ergebnis2 = 0
faktor2 = 1

while (dezimalneu > 0) and dezpos > 0:
    print dezimalneu
    dezimalneu *= basis
    faktor2 *= 10
    i = int(dezimalneu)
    ergebnis2 = ergebnis2 *10 + i
    dezimalneu -= i
    dezpos -= 1

ergebnis2 = 1.0 * ergebnis2 / faktor2
ergebnisfinal = ergebnis + ergebnis2

print "eingegebene Zahl", zahl, "- neue Zahl mit der Basis %d =" % (basis) , ergebnisfinal/10
```

(I kept the german variable names, because I have begun to write it before it was translated)

Answer (score 0):

The subtraction is wrong. `dezimalnew == rest2`, if you look closely at the assignment, so it will give 0.

What I'd say is that you may need to review in general how to convert from a decimal floating number to any base. The general idea, is once you have the 0.1 for example (the floating part), you want to keep multiplying by the base and adding the INTEGER part of the new result to the converted number, then keeping only the new decimal part.
For example, 0.1 to 3 gives `0.002200...` because:
`0.1 * 3 = (0).3 * 3 = (0).9 * 3 = (2).7, 0.7 * 3 = (2).1, 0.1 * 3 = 0.3...`